# Best practices for loading and refreshing time-sensitive data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

**SUMMARY OF THE PROBLEM**

I am writing an iOS app that is like a hybrid between a to-do list and a calendar. Unlike a to-do list, you don't check things off as complete. Rather the to-do's are slotted into sections in a UITableView for Active and Inactive. The problem is that the section and sorting could change at any time relative to the current date and time.

This is my first iOS app and I really want to make sure that I'm learning best practices. I'm really struggling with when and where to refresh the fetched data when the app first launches, when it returns from the background, when a notification has fired, and possibly even refreshing on a timer when in the foreground.

Currently the app loads the core data just fine and the view controller adjusts the section and sort order of the rows properly when a record is added, changed, or deleted. I also am able to refresh an individual record when it's notification is triggered when my app is in the foreground. i.e. Since the notification triggered, non-recurring reminders move from Active to Inactive and recurring reminders set their section and next alert date as well.

So I'm currently struggling most with:

1. **Initial Load**. How and when to refresh the section/nextAlert date upon initial application load after the data is fetched but before the view controller starts displaying it.
2. **App Enters Foreground**. How and when to refresh the data when the app moves into the foreground. This is needed because if a notification is delivered while the app is in the background, the app doesn't get triggered until the user interacts with the notification. Once the user interacts with the notification (including simply dismissing it), I update refresh the section and date but if the user ignores the notification and loads the app, the data is stale.
3. **Time Has Passed**. How and when to refresh the data while the user is in the app, time has passed, and the dat should be refreshed. This is really only necessary to get around issue #2 above.
4. [Added] **Can't Launch x-callback-url from Notification**. [I added this since my original post because it could have an effect on how/when/where to do things in my app.] The whole point of the reminders in my app is that the user can launch another app from my apps notifications using an x-callback-url. I've noticed that if my app has been closed, the notifications still deliver, but when the user takes an action on the notification it simply opens my app to the main table view but doesn't actually perform the action of launching the other app that its supposed to. I literally have no idea why and of course I can't debug the app while its closed ;-) So I'm looking for help on this as well.

If it matters, I also in turn expect to add x-callback-url functionality to my own app as well. I'd like other apps to be able to create, update, or delete reminder records. The code related to my notification handling is below.

5. **General Best Practices**. I've followed tutorials from Apple and many others and looked at all sorts of code and I feel like I'm doing things the way that they should be done. I'm "binding" the core data to the table view controller and fetching data in viewDidLoad. However, it makes for a really fat view controller. I'm interested in perhaps using this method of breaking out all the core data code into essentially a "Model Controller". https://medium.com/@maddy.lucky4u/swift-4-core-data-part-3-creating-a-singleton-core-data-refactoring-insert-update-delete-9811af2fcf75 This seems like it would be great! The view controller is much cleaner/skinnier and I think I can even "hide" all the optional unwrapping ugliness in there. And if you all end up telling me that to solve my problems I need to move the fetching and refreshing somewhere else, such as in the AppDelegate, that would be easier too.

**BACKGROUND ON WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I have looked into and tried many different things to address the problems.

1. **Refresh in viewDidLoad After Fetch**. I have tried to call a refreshReminders function right after the fetch in the table view controller during viewDidLoad. That seems to work fine as long as I don't actually save to core data in that function. Just setting the fields on the record/records triggers the controller and the rows move and update as they should. Although it seems like maybe this is too late in the load sequence. Do we really want the table view to have to move records around right when the app launches for the first time? That sounds like a bad practice.

Now if I try to save the changes to core data after the refresh, this is where it get really weird. The table is clearly getting updated based on the changes to the records within the current context, but when the context gets saved, it triggers the changes again! Since the changes have already been made, the app crashes on trying to move a row from an old location to a new location after it has already been moved. See code below.

3. **Refresh in viewWillAppear**. I have tried calling refreshReminders from viewWillAppear as I would think that would trigger both on initial load as well as after the app enters the foreground. It does work just the same as in viewDidLoad in that if don't save the context, it moves the records properly. If I do save the context, I get the same error as in viewDidLoad.

However, it doesn't actually trigger when the app comes back into the foreground which is perplexing to me.

It also has the negative side effect of triggering when we segue back from the detail view/edit screen. We don't need that since the segue already handles creating a new record or updating an existing one and saving the context.

3. **Refresh Before Fetch Awakes**. I have used an extension to the core data object (Reminders) to set the section and nextAlert date. However, this doesn't appear to do ANYTHING. i.e. The table still loads with the reminders in the wrong section and/or sort order.

Refreshing the fields here also doesn't mark the data as "dirty" (changed), so the table view controller doesn't move it and the context save that only gets triggered if the data is dirty doesn't get triggered of course. I've even tried to save the context after the fetch without checking if its changed, but that doesn't do anything either. i.e. core data really doesn't think anything HAS changed even if it has.

4. **Refresh On a Timer**. I have NOT tried to refreshReminders based on a timer yet. I figure that if I can't even get a refresh to work during initial load and return to foreground, then essentially "randomly" calling for a refresh based on a timer would most certainly cause a crash. Interestingly though, I have temporarily enabled pull-to-refresh and it seems I can do that at any time and it works fine.

**HERE IS THE CODE**

1. **Refresh After Fetch** and 2. **Refresh in viewWillAppear**

This is the .move case in my tableViewController's controller function

```
case .move:
            if let oldPath = indexPath, let newPath = newIndexPath {
                os_log("RemindersViewController: Move was triggered, now updating row in table. Old path was %{public}@ and new path is %{public}@", log: OSLog.default, type: .info, oldPath as CVarArg, newPath as CVarArg)
RemindersCell, withReminder: anObject as! Reminders)
                configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: oldPath) as! RemindersCell, withReminder: anObject as! Reminders)
                os_log("RemindersViewController: updated moved cell.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)


                // Don't actually try to move it if the old and new path are the same
                if (newPath != oldPath) {
                    os_log("RemindersViewController: Moving row in table.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)
                    tableView.moveRow(at: oldPath, to: newPath)
                    os_log("RemindersViewController: row moved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)
                }
            }
```

This is a simplified version of my configureCell function.

```
    func configureCell(_ cell: RemindersCell, withReminder reminder: Reminders) {
        cell.labelTitleField!.text = reminder.title ?? "New Reminder"
        cell.labelAlertField!.text = reminder.nextAlert!.description
    }
```

This is what is in the console related to that code:

```
2019-03-23 12:31:09.307801-0500 Scheduler[5711:2218287] RemindersViewContoller in viewDidLoad: Fetched records successfully.
Refreshing reminders!
2019-03-23 12:31:09.311755-0500 Scheduler[5711:2218287] Reminder 'Test Non-recurring Reminder' section updated to Inactive.
2019-03-23 12:31:09.313254-0500 Scheduler[5711:2218287] RemindersViewController: Move was triggered, now updating row in table. Old path was <NSIndexPath: 0x28078e480> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} and new path is <NSIndexPath: 0x28078f140> {length = 2, path = 1 - 2}
Scheduler was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb)
```

So it appears that the OS itself has moved the reminder where it belongs, somehow without using my controller function. That must happen when the individual reminder fields are refreshed, but then when I save the context to core data, it calls my controller function again to do the move that has already been done.

4. [Added] **Can't Launch x-callback-url from Notification**

```
    // Handle notifications when our app is in the background
    // Note that this isn't triggered when the notification is delivered, but rather when the user interacts with the notification
    //
    // TO-DO: THIS DOESN'T RUN THE SHORTCUT IF THE APP WAS CLOSED WHEN THE NOTIFICATION WAS RESPONDED TO!!!
    //
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {

        // Get the user info from the notification
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Get the specific record id that triggered this notification
        let itemID = userInfo["ITEM_ID"] as? String
        let itemTitle = userInfo["ITEM_TITLE"] as? String
        let itemShortcut = userInfo["ITEM_SHORTCUT"] as? String
        let itemURL = userInfo["ITEM_URL"] as? String

        // Handle the notification action
        print("RemindersViewController: Received notification. actionIdentifier:", response.actionIdentifier)
        switch response.actionIdentifier {

        // If user selected the Run Shortcut option or simply tapped the notification, run the associated shortcut
        case "RUN_SHORTCUT", "com.apple.UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier":
            os_log("RemindersViewController: Notification Action Received: RUN_SHORTCUT: %{public}@ for shortcut %{public}@", log: .default, type: .info, String(describing: itemTitle!), String(describing: itemShortcut!))
            if (itemShortcut != nil && itemShortcut != "") {
                if (itemURL != nil) {
                    print("RemindersViewController: Shortcut URL=", itemURL!)
                    let launchURL = URL(string: itemURL!)
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(launchURL!) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(launchURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                            print("RemindersViewController: Notification Action: Run shortcut: Open url : \(success)")
                        })
                    } else {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You don't have the Shortcuts app installed", message: "Please download from the Apple App Store", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(action)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        print("RemindersViewController: Notification Action: User doesn't have the Shortcuts app.")
                    }
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You don't have a shortcut name filled in", message: "Please fill in a shortcut name on your reminder", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(action)
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print("RemindersViewController: Notification Action: No shortcut name filled in!")
                }
            }
            break

        default:
            os_log("RemindersViewController: Default action selected, which is: %{public}@. Doing nothing.", log: .default, type: .info, response.actionIdentifier)
            break
        }

        // Regardless of what the response was, update the reminder with section and nextAlert date
        // REMOVE THIS once we auto-refresh when the app enters the foreground again as that will take care of it
        if (itemID != nil) {
            print("Refreshing reminder from the notification.")
            refreshReminder(stringURI: itemID!)
        }

        // Call the completion handler to close out the notification
        completionHandler()
    }
```

**EXPECTED AND ACTUAL RESULTS**

I think I've covered that above, but in summary I want to know best practices around how and when to refresh time-dependent data upon initial load, return to foreground, and as time passes. [Added] I also expect that notification actions while my app is closed will still perform the function (calling another app via x-callback-url) when the user requests that.

Comment: Hi Tim. Welcome to SO. It’s unlikely that anyone will answer your question as it stands. You are asking for opinions and you are asking about multiple abstract design and patterning issues rather than one specific concrete problem. You may wish to look for blogs around MVVM and MVC patterns to help you with your design and come back with a more directed question later.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding! I have been able to solve so many problems just by searching here! But I think I'm still missing the "big picture" so I tried to lay it all out for some general guidance. I'm really looking for someone to say "this isn't normally done, but in your case you really need to move all this core data handling to the AppDelegate so you can do these refreshes on state changes before the view controller is even loaded" or whatever. I'll break each of the 5 problems out into separate posts though from your advice.

Comment: I have posted problem #1 about initial data fetch and refresh here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318631/how-do-i-update-fields-that-are-dependent-on-the-current-time-after-a-fetch-to-c

Comment: Here is my separate post for problem #4 regarding custom notification actions not completing when my app was initially closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319237/how-can-i-process-a-notification-action-when-my-app-is-closed

Comment: With help I have been able to resolve the issue with a row move crashing the table view controller! See answer in above post.