# How do I update fields that are dependent on the current time after a fetch to core data but before the table view is displayed?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

**SUMMARY OF THE PROBLEM**

I am writing an iOS app that is like a hybrid between a to-do list and a calendar. Unlike a to-do list, you don't check things off as complete. Rather the to-do's are slotted into sections in a UITableView for Active and Inactive. The problem is that the section and sorting could change at any time relative to the current date and time.

So I'm currently struggling most with how and when to refresh the section/nextAlert date upon initial application load after the data is fetched but before the view controller starts displaying it.

**BACKGROUND ON WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I have looked into and tried many different things to address the problems.

1. **Refresh in viewDidLoad After Fetch**. I have tried to call a refreshReminders function right after the fetch in the table view controller during viewDidLoad. That seems to work fine as long as I don't actually save to core data in that function. Just setting the fields on the record/records triggers the controller and the rows move and update as they should. Although it seems like maybe this is too late in the load sequence. Do we really want the table view to have to move records around right when the app launches for the first time? That sounds like a bad practice.

Now if I try to save the changes to core data after the refresh, this is where it get really weird. The table is clearly getting updated based on the changes to the records within the current context, but when the context gets saved, it triggers the changes again! Since the changes have already been made, the app crashes on trying to move a row from an old location to a new location after it has already been moved. See code below.

2. **Refresh Before Fetch Awakes**. I have also tried to use an extension to the core data object (Reminders) to set the section and nextAlert date. However, this doesn't appear to do ANYTHING. i.e. The table still loads with the reminders in the wrong section and/or sort order.

Refreshing the fields here also doesn't mark the data as "dirty" (changed), so the table view controller doesn't move it and the context save that only gets triggered if the data is dirty doesn't get triggered of course. I've even tried to save the context after the fetch without checking if its changed, but that doesn't do anything either. i.e. core data really doesn't think anything HAS changed even if it has.

**HERE IS THE CODE**

This is the .move case in my tableViewController's controller function

```
case .move:
            if let oldPath = indexPath, let newPath = newIndexPath {
                os_log("RemindersViewController: Move was triggered, now updating row in table. Old path was %{public}@ and new path is %{public}@", log: OSLog.default, type: .info, oldPath as CVarArg, newPath as CVarArg)
RemindersCell, withReminder: anObject as! Reminders)
                configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: oldPath) as! RemindersCell, withReminder: anObject as! Reminders)
                os_log("RemindersViewController: updated moved cell.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)


                // Don't actually try to move it if the old and new path are the same
                if (newPath != oldPath) {
                    os_log("RemindersViewController: Moving row in table.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)
                    tableView.moveRow(at: oldPath, to: newPath)
                    os_log("RemindersViewController: row moved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)
                }
            }
```

This is a simplified version of my configureCell function.

```
    func configureCell(_ cell: RemindersCell, withReminder reminder: Reminders) {
        cell.labelTitleField!.text = reminder.title ?? "New Reminder"
        cell.labelAlertField!.text = reminder.nextAlert!.description
    }
```

I am using beginUpdates() and endUpdates() to batch the updates so that if there are a ton of changes at once the OS can figure out the best way to process the changes and animate all the movements at the same time.

```
// Batch the updates to the table. Start with beginUpdates so all the action animations are queued up.
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }
```

```
// Batch the updates to the table. End with endUpdates to trigger the actual animations.
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

This is what is in the console related to that code:

```
2019-03-23 12:31:09.307801-0500 Scheduler[5711:2218287] RemindersViewContoller in viewDidLoad: Fetched records successfully.
Refreshing reminders!
2019-03-23 12:31:09.311755-0500 Scheduler[5711:2218287] Reminder 'Test Non-recurring Reminder' section updated to Inactive.
2019-03-23 12:31:09.313254-0500 Scheduler[5711:2218287] RemindersViewController: Move was triggered, now updating row in table. Old path was <NSIndexPath: 0x28078e480> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} and new path is <NSIndexPath: 0x28078f140> {length = 2, path = 1 - 2}
Scheduler was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb)
```

So it appears that the OS itself has moved the reminder where it belongs, somehow without using my controller function. That must happen when the individual reminder fields are refreshed, but then when I save the context to core data, it calls my controller function again to do the move that has already been done.

**EXPECTED AND ACTUAL RESULTS**

I think I've covered that above, but in summary I want to know what best way is to alter fetched data before the table view displays it so that it is all in the correct sections and sort order relative to the current date and time.

**UPDATES**

Here is the refreshReminder routine that works perfectly as long as saving to core data is commented out. This function is called immediately after I perform the initial fetch of the reminder records:

```
// Handle updating nextAlert and section based on current date and time
func refreshReminders () {

        // Loop through the records and update the time-sensitive section and nextAlert fields
        print("Refreshing reminders!")
        for reminder in fetchedController.fetchedObjects! {
            if (reminder.nextAlert! < Date()) {
                if (reminder.recurrence != "Never") {
                    let nextAlert = nextAlertDate(alertDate: reminder.alert!, recurrencePattern: reminder.recurrence)
                    if (reminder.nextAlert != nextAlert) {
                        reminder.nextAlert = nextAlert
                        os_log("Reminder '%{public}@' nextAlert date updated to %{public}@.", reminder.title!, String(describing: reminder.nextAlert!))
                    }
                }
                let section = getSection(nextAlertDate: reminder.nextAlert!)
                if (reminder.section != section) {
                    reminder.section = section
                    //print("Reminder section updated to", reminder.section!)
                    os_log("Reminder '%{public}@' section updated to %{public}@.", reminder.title!, reminder.section!)
                }
            }
        } //endfor

        // Save changes to core data if there are any
        /*if context.hasChanges {
             do {
             try context.save()
                 print("RemindersViewController in refreshReminders: Changes to core data, so saving them now.")
             } catch {
                 // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                 // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                 let nserror = error as NSError
                 fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
             } //enddo
         }*/ //endif

    } //endfunc refreshReminders
```

Here are the results of it updating/moving a reminder from one section to the other on initial app launch because it's reminder time has passed:

```
2019-03-23 18:26:24.796406-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371662] AppDelegate: Initialized core data stack
2019-03-23 18:26:24.801211-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371734] AppDelegate: Notification authorization granted.
2019-03-23 18:26:24.806165-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371734] AppDelegate: Set our custom notification categories and actions.
2019-03-23 18:26:24.810726-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371662] RemindersViewContoller in viewDidLoad: Fetched records successfully.
Refreshing reminders!
2019-03-23 18:26:24.814331-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371662] Reminder 'Test Non-recurring Reminder' section updated to Inactive.
Number of sections: 2
2019-03-23 18:26:24.815463-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371662] RemindersViewController in viewWillAppear: We're here. Let's see how often we get triggered!
Number of sections: 2
Number of records in section 1 : 3
Number of records in section 0 : 7
Number of sections: 2
Number of records in section 1 : 3
Number of records in section 0 : 7
2019-03-23 18:26:24.893329-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371662] RemindersViewController: Move was triggered, now updating row in table. Old path was <NSIndexPath: 0x28047a900> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} and new path is <NSIndexPath: 0x28047a920> {length = 2, path = 1 - 3}
2019-03-23 18:26:24.893498-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371662] RemindersViewController: updated moved cell.
2019-03-23 18:26:24.893511-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371662] RemindersViewController: Moving row in table.
2019-03-23 18:26:24.893524-0500 Scheduler[6383:2371662] RemindersViewController: row moved.
Number of sections: 2
Number of sections: 2
Number of records in section 0 : 6
Number of records in section 1 : 4
```

Here is the os_log and error when I uncomment out saving to core data. It crashes on the configCell.

```
2019-03-23 18:35:22.210467-0500 Scheduler[6396:2375020] AppDelegate: Initialized core data stack
2019-03-23 18:35:22.215964-0500 Scheduler[6396:2375092] AppDelegate: Notification authorization granted.
2019-03-23 18:35:22.220937-0500 Scheduler[6396:2375092] AppDelegate: Set our custom notification categories and actions.
2019-03-23 18:35:22.227273-0500 Scheduler[6396:2375020] RemindersViewContoller in viewDidLoad: Fetched records successfully.
Refreshing reminders!
2019-03-23 18:35:22.230832-0500 Scheduler[6396:2375020] Reminder 'Test Non-recurring Reminder' section updated to Inactive.
2019-03-23 18:35:22.232326-0500 Scheduler[6396:2375020] RemindersViewController: Move was triggered, now updating row in table. Old path was <NSIndexPath: 0x282e6d360> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} and new path is <NSIndexPath: 0x282e6df60> {length = 2, path = 1 - 3}
Scheduler was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb)
```

```
configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: oldPath) as! RemindersCell, withReminder: anObject as! Reminders)
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x104048220)
```

Comment: Possibly the simplest solution is not use a `FetchedResultsController`  Or maybe try a `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` in your `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have beginUpdates / endUpdates in use. I'll update the post to show the functions that handle that. As to the fetchedController, I want to use that to effectively "bind" the core data to the table view so it handles fetching additional records when needed, etc.

Comment: What I can't figure out for the life of me is how/why is the OS updating the table view without calling my controller and then calling my controller which crashes because the actual updates have been handled "behind the scenes".

Comment: All updates happen through your code. Nothing happens behind the scenes. You could update your question to show the crash you are getting

Comment: Sorry, I meant to do that. Its the line: configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: oldPath) as! RemindersCell, withReminder: anObject as! Reminders).

Comment: `cellForRow` will return `nil` if that row isn't on screen. In that case you get an exception because you are force unwrapping. You should conditionally unwrap it.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to configureCell(tableView.cellForRow(at: oldPath)! as! RemindersCell, withReminder: reminder) which I believe force unwraps it, but it still crashes. But also, there must be something much more important going on timing-wise that the controller would be called and there wouldn't be a cell visible if I save the context first, but if I just change the fields of the reminder without saving the context, the cell is available and everything works just fine.

Comment: You don't want to force unwrap. That will crash. You must conditionally unwrap `cellforRow`.  `if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: oldPath) as? RemindersCell, let reminder = anObject as? Reminders {  configureCell(cell, withReminder: reminder) }`. You need to have a good reason to use ! because it always carries the risk of a crash

Comment: Thanks so much! I forgot to mention I am new to iOS programming and these optionals are confusing. That certainly sounds like best practice to use an if let foo, let bar { code that needs foo and bar }.

Comment: Although this didn't fix my issue at all. The new logic just says if any of the fields that should be filled for a move aren't filled, then skip the move. Then I get the error about a mismatch between the number of records in each section (because the move was skipped). :-(

Comment: Then don't skip the move. Moving isn't related to whether the cell is onscreen.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this Paul! I still don't understand why the timing is off a bit and a move would be triggered even though the cell isn't valid (returns nil), but I guess its just a question of where the OS is at with loading the data into the table view. I have updated my code to only configure the cell if the cell is valid, but to do the move regardless and it works! I'll go ahead post this with my updated code in the answer. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Because you are using a `FetchedResultsController` the move is triggered by changes in your data model; If the move was triggered by the user re-ordering rows (drag/drop) then you would expect the cell to be on screen.  With changes in the data model the cell may not be on screen.  You should always practice defensive coding.  Any time you use a ! in Swift, you should ask your self if it is necessary; when could it fail? If it does fail is crashing the only option you have?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it is possible that a move row request can be sent even if the cell itself is nil. PaulW11 indicates that is likely because the cell isn't actually visible on the screen yet. So the way to handle this is to update (configure) the cell if and only if it isn't nil, but to go ahead and process the row move as long as we have a valid oldPath and newPath. My updated code that works great is:

```
case .move:
            // If we have an old and new path, proceed with moving and/or updating the cell
            if let oldPath = indexPath, let newPath = newIndexPath {

                if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: oldPath) as? RemindersCell, let reminder = anObject as? Reminders {
                    os_log("RemindersViewController: Move was triggered, so updating cell in table. Reminder is: %{public}@", log: .default, type: .info, reminder)
                    configureCell(cell, withReminder: reminder)
                    os_log("RemindersViewController: Updated moving cell.", log: .default, type: .info)
                } else {
                    os_log("RemindersViewController: Move triggered, but cell isn't yet visible so skipping updating the cell fields.")
                }

            // If we have an old and new path, then go ahead and move the cell
            os_log("RemindersViewController: Moving row in table.", log: .default, type: .info)
            tableView.moveRow(at: oldPath, to: newPath)
                os_log("RemindersViewController: Row moved from %{public}@ to %{public}@.", log: .default, type: .info, oldPath as CVarArg, newPath as CVarArg)

            // If old and new path invalid, then log that
            } else {
                os_log("RemindersViewController: Move triggered, but old and new path aren't filled, so ignoring it.", log: .default, type: .error)
            }
            break
```