# How can I process a notification action when my app is closed?

Tags: ios, notifications

**SUMMARY OF THE PROBLEM**

I am writing an iOS app that sends reminder notifications to let a user run other apps via their x-callback-url. I have everything working perfectly if the app is in the foreground or background, but it won't work when my app is closed.

When my app is closed, the notifications deliver properly as well and the user can dismiss it or choose a custom actions to launch another app via it's x-callback-url. My app launches just fine when the user takes any action on the notification.

What doesn't work when the app is launched directly from a closed state is triggering launching the x-callback-url to launch the Shortcuts app.

**HERE IS THE CODE**

This is the code that is in my AppDelegate related to notifications:

```
    // Handle what we need to after the initial application load
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Setup our custom notification options and notification category.
        // Note that The table view controller will register to handle the actual notification actions.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) {(granted, Error) in
            if !granted {
                os_log("AppDelegate: Notification authorization NOT granted.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)
            } else {
                os_log("AppDelegate: Notification authorization granted.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)

                // Define our custom notification actions
                let runAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "RUN_SHORTCUT", title: "Run Shortcut", options: [.foreground])
                let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "SNOOZE", title: "Snooze 10 Minutes", options: [])
                let skipAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "SKIP_SHORTCUT", title: "Skip Shortcut", options: [])

                // Define our custom notification categories
                let shortcutCategory =
                    UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "SHORTCUT_REMINDER", actions: [snoozeAction, runAction, skipAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: .customDismissAction)
                let noshortcutCategory =
                    UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "NO_SHORTCUT_REMINDER", actions: [snoozeAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: .customDismissAction)

                // Register the nofication category and actions with iOS
                let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                notificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([shortcutCategory, noshortcutCategory])
                os_log("AppDelegate: Set our custom notification categories and actions.", log: OSLog.default, type: .info)

            } //endif
        } //endfunc

        return true
    }
```

This is the code in my main table view controller that is the delegate to receive the notifications:

```
    // Handle notifications when our app is in the background
    // Note that this isn't triggered when the notification is delivered, but rather when the user interacts with the notification
    //
    // TO-DO: THIS DOESN'T RUN THE SHORTCUT IF THE APP WAS CLOSED WHEN THE NOTIFICATION WAS RESPONDED TO!!!
    //
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {

        // Get the user info from the notification
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Get the specific record id that triggered this notification
        let itemID = userInfo["ITEM_ID"] as? String
        let itemTitle = userInfo["ITEM_TITLE"] as? String
        let itemShortcut = userInfo["ITEM_SHORTCUT"] as? String
        let itemURL = userInfo["ITEM_URL"] as? String

        // Handle the notification action
        print("RemindersViewController: Received notification. actionIdentifier:", response.actionIdentifier)
        switch response.actionIdentifier {

        // If user selected the Run Shortcut option or simply tapped the notification, run the associated shortcut
        case "RUN_SHORTCUT", "com.apple.UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier":
            os_log("RemindersViewController: Notification Action Received: RUN_SHORTCUT: %{public}@ for shortcut %{public}@", log: .default, type: .info, String(describing: itemTitle!), String(describing: itemShortcut!))
            if (itemShortcut != nil && itemShortcut != "") {
                if (itemURL != nil) {
                    print("RemindersViewController: Shortcut URL=", itemURL!)
                    let launchURL = URL(string: itemURL!)
                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(launchURL!) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(launchURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                            print("RemindersViewController: Notification Action: Run shortcut: Open url : \(success)")
                        })
                    } else {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You don't have the Shortcuts app installed", message: "Please download from the Apple App Store", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(action)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        print("RemindersViewController: Notification Action: User doesn't have the Shortcuts app.")
                    }
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You don't have a shortcut name filled in", message: "Please fill in a shortcut name on your reminder", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(action)
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print("RemindersViewController: Notification Action: No shortcut name filled in!")
                }
            }
            break

        default:
            os_log("RemindersViewController: Default action selected, which is: %{public}@. Doing nothing.", log: .default, type: .info, response.actionIdentifier)
            break
        }


        // Call the completion handler to close out the notification
        completionHandler()
    }
```

**EXPECTED AND ACTUAL RESULTS**

I expect that when the app is launched from a closed state due to user interaction with a notification, that the custom "Run Shortcut" action should launch the Shortcuts app with its x-callback-url stored in the notification user data.

Comment: As an update: I have now specified the Run Shortcut action with both .foreground and .authenticationRequired to ensure that the app will get loaded and the user has to unlock their device. I figured perhaps the issue was that the app couldn't launch another app while the device was locked. But alas, that didn't fix anything. For some reason the app won't launch another app if my app was closed when the notification is acted upon.

Comment: I also want to do that. And that is when user clear the notification, I want to get the userInfo data, and want to save it somewhere in D.B . But the problem is when user clear the notification, when my app is closed/terminated. I missed the information in the notification sent by my server. So How do I recover this situation, or How can I check up on clear notification action?